# Efficient computation of influence from node u to node v in network igraph R

Tags: r, igraph

As the title says,having computed all the paths starting from node u and ending to node v,i have to compute the influence of node u to node v "I(u,v)" by the following type: 

`I(u,v) = Sum(for all the paths from u to v)[ Product of all the weights of consecutive edges from u to v ]`

This is the way i do it:

```
Alpha<-array(0,dim = c(length(V(g)),length(V(g))))
if( u!=v ){
paths<-all_simple_paths(g, from = V(g)[u])#computing all paths from u
UpathV<-paths[unlist(lapply(paths, function(p){p[length(p)] %in% v}))]#extracting those that end to v
if(length(UpathV)!=0){#computing probability matrix from u to v
          Flist<-array(NA,dim = c(length(UpathV),max(lengths(UpathV))))
          Flist[1:length(UpathV)]<-1
          for(i in 1:length(UpathV)){
            for(j in 2:length(UpathV[[i]])){
              Flist[i,j]<-Flist[i,j-1]*E(g)[get.edge.ids(g,as.numeric(UpathV[[i]][(j-1):j]))]$weight
            }
          }
        }#if length(pspaths)
        if(length(UpathV)!=0){
          for(i in 1:length(UpathV)){
            Alpha[u,v]<-Alpha[u,v]+Flist[i,length(UpathV[[i]])]            
          }#computing I(u,v)
        }  
  }else{
        Alpha[u,v]<-1
  }
```

where Alpha[u,v] is I(u,v) and Flist[i,j] is for path i the probability of u till the jth node heading to v.
In line 
`Flist<-array(NA,dim=c(length(UpathV),max(lengths(UpathV))))`
u can see that if the 3rd path is 1->2->3->4 then it has length of 4 and then Flist[3,4] is the weight of edge w(1->2)*w(2->3)*w(3->4).
My solution is working but for large networks it takes way much time to compute the matrix.Given the fact that i have to compute I(u,v) from every u to every v i need to know if there is a more efficient way to do my calculations without changing lines 3-4.Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a while i found a way to make the computations faster by changing 1 line of code and adding another one.
When computing the Flist array instead of getting every weight value from E(g)$weight we should instead get it from the adjacency matrix.I found out that in R it is way faster to do things with matrices than dataframes.So add:

`AjM<-as_adjacency_matrix(g,attr = "weight")`

and:

`Flist[i,j]<-Flist[i,j-1]*AjM[as.numeric(UpathV[[i]][j-1]),as.numeric(UpathV[[i]][j])]`